How to have phone number in form registration with Tutor LMS?
We are working on a website with Tutor LMS, and we want to make the "Phone number" obligatory in registration form on WordPress !
Does anyone have an idea about that ?
I made some reseach online and didn't found an answer

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
